# How come the outcome of my collatz function isn't the same as it is supposed to be when I put large numbers?

Tags: python

So I got this Python code where it should give me the amount of steps for each number when we apply the Collatz algorithm on it.

When I input small integers, it gives the correct amount of steps. But when I input large numbers, it gives me the wrong number of steps.

Here's a code that reproduces the same thing:

```
import math

number = 931386509544713451 # Number here

def collatz_algorithm(n):
    x = math.floor(n)
    A_N = 0
    while x != 1:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x / 2
        else:
            x = 3*x + 1
        A_N += 1
    print("\nNumber of steps for {}: {}".format(str(n),str(A_N)))
 
collatz_algorithm(number)
```

When you input small numbers such as `7`, it does just fine and it gives the right number of steps. But when you input a large number as `931386509544713451`, it gives the wrong number of steps (As shown in the Wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

I tried to do many things, such as converting to `ulonglong` with `ctypes` but still didn't work, I was thinking it could increase the number limit, but it didn't.

So could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = x / 2` is converting your number to a `float` which is imprecise. Replace it with `x = x // 2` so that integer division will be used.

Output (matches Wikipedia):

> ```
> Number of steps for 931386509544713451: 2283
> ```

Comment: Damn, thanks, I didn't think float division was imprecise. Thanks for letting me know and thanks for correcting my code!

Comment: @ElmatadorDeAngel happy to help, for more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken